# Assembly: 32 bit floating point instructions on an 8 bit chip

Tags: assembly, floating-point, avr, atmega

I was trying to help a friend doing some assembly code on an 8 bit AVR chip (The Atmega8535) but my assembly knowledge is quite slim and mostly centered around modern day chips and not some obsolete fossil.

So it boils down to the question of how to add *two* 32 bit floating points in an 8 bit architecture that doesn't even support floating point specific instruction sets such as FADD...

```
; 3.1415926 (pi) is given by 0x40 0x49 0x0F 0xDA
; 2.7182818 (e)  is given by 0x40 0x2D 0xF8 0x54
```

For the interested [here](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc2502.pdf) is a datasheet for the chip in question. The instruction set starts at page 301.

Comment: http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BinMath/addFloat.html

Comment: same way any other fixed point machine does floating point math.  which is the same way you did math in grade school.  with add you line up your decimal points (exponents have to match), do the addition.  then for float you might have to normalize one decimal place.  basically you are not going to do this assembly if you dont already know how, and even if you do, that would be crazy, just get the source to a working library and compile it or get the object of a compiled library and link it in and call it.

Comment: this is the same way the hardware does it to if you had a hardware fpu.

Comment: you could also ask the same questions of how do I do 32 bit fixed point math on a 32 bit machine (which you have to solve if you want to do float).  how do I multiply or divide on a machine that has neither, or how do I do X bit multiply/divide on a machine that only does Y bits.  The Hackers Delight is a good book for basics on how to do these kinds of things along with shortcuts.  Note that if you choose to do this at all the library you need is going to be quite large and consume a noticeable amount of your program space.

Comment: Unfortunately the task is for it to be done in this obsolete 8 bit AVR, as crazy as it sounds, there is no way around it (such as linking or using external libraries).

Comment: If you are not used to the IEEE 754 32 bit FP numbers (I assume this is the format) I suggest you to take a look at how they are represented, try some addition by hand, then implement an algorithm in C using only char data type, then converting to assembly. Unless this is an homework or similar you can look for a compiler for the old AVR chip, this will let you code in C (however all the fun will be gone).

Comment: @BlooIt Not crazy at all. Until roughly the late 80's floating point units in any PC were rare and expensive accessories - if they were available at all. Compilers just generated calls to libraries that used integer instructions to implement the floating point math. It's slow, works just fine. Even if you can't use a library, extracting code from it to do what has to be done is a way forward.

Comment: 8 bit AVRs are current state-of-the-art technology and far from obsolete. Try to get an Intel 32 bit CPU + power supplies + memory controller + RAM + non-volatile memory + ADC + serial interface controllers + ... in an 8 pin package for less than US$ 1.

Comment: "using external libraries" is not an option? Then this is an excercise a.k.a homework, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think you have the following options:

- look at the avr-libc for implementation details
- write your program in c. 
  I bet that avr-gcc writes better (in terms of efficiency *and* correctness) assembly code than you
- use an easier number format. eg:

  - some fixed point format with fix scaling
  - some fast floating point format without the IEEE overhead. dependent of your requirements eg:

    - 8bit/16bit mantissa, 8 bit exponent.
    - something like Analog Devices shown in their blackfin app note: http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/EE.185.Rev.4.08.07.pdf

Also a good source for basic understanding is the following book:

"Software Manual for the Elementary Functions"
by William J. Cody, William Waite

It shows how to implement various (also basic) operations and algorithms only with integer based arithmetics.

Comment: Assuming the OP needs some homework done, this is a really great answer to help him learn what he needs to. +1

Answer (score 3):

> So it boils down to the question of how to add two 32 bit floating points in an 8 bit architecture that doesn't even support floating point specific instruction sets such as FADD

The avr-libc library does it [like this](http://svn.savannah.nongnu.org/viewvc/trunk/avr-libc/libm/fplib/addsf3x.S?root=avr-libc&view=markup). Therefore you should too.